# How to remove opposite rows from SQL table

Tags: sql, set, unordered

I have the following SQL table:

```
A|B
---
w|x
x|w
y|z
z|y
```

Can I construct a query which will yield the following result:

```
A|B
---
w|x
y|z
```

To summarize, I would like to treat the two columns as an unordered set, such that (a,b) == (b,a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *"best"* code depends on the database, but following is dbms-agnostic:

```
SELECT      t.A,
            t.B
FROM        my_table t
LEFT JOIN   my_table t2
        ON  t.A = t2.B
        AND t.B = t2.A
        AND t.A < t.B
WHERE       t2.A IS NULL
```

Comment: +1: I was about to edit my answer and add this one too :) Use `t.A > t.B` though, to get the specified results (`w|x` instead of `x|w`).

Comment: Damn. I was so close to having this, I left out the ordering comparison and so my results were always nil.

Comment: I'd say `w<x` and `y<z`, but what do I know :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
SELECT LEAST(a,b) a, GREATEST(a,b) b
FROM t
GROUP BY LEAST(a,b), GREATEST(a,b)
```

---

With the following test-table `t`:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( a VARCHAR(1), b VARCHAR(1) );

INSERT INTO t VALUES ('w','x'),('x','w'),('y','z'),('z','y');
```

it returns:

```
w  x
y  z
```

Using `LEAST` and `GREATEST` also makes sure that `w x` is returned instead of `x w`.

Comment: Didn't know about `least` and `greatest`. Nice. Wouldn't `distinct` work here as well?

Comment: Yes, `DISTINCT` would return the same in this case. You would have to test performance, but I guess it would be the same.